# Appropriate use of "app" vs "application"

Tags: word-choice, formality, software

Can *app* serve as an accepted abbreviation for *application* in formal contexts? Is there some context where *app* is more accepted (for example, when talking about mobile applications)?

Comment: Personally, I've always thought of *app* as short for *applet* (i.e. - a relatively trivial piece of software, regardless of how important it may become to some users). I'm sure some people call things like *Autocad* and *Photoshop* "apps", but mostly I think apps are little utility-type things you run on a smartphone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is right. Nowadays, when people say "app" they mean "mobile application."

If you want to talk about an application that doesn't run on a tablet/phone, you can say something is a "Windows app". If you don't want to specify the operating system except to say that it's not a mobile application, just go with "application" or "program".

Comment: is the word "app" itself acceptable (for formal documents), partially acceptable or is it just a slang?

Comment: It's slang. "Mobile applications" for formal documents.

Comment: It isn't slang. The OED records it as 'computing colloquial' (with, incidentally, the earliest citation dated 1985).

Comment: In fact, "app" has been used for application in electronics since at least 1971, and for computer programs since at 1983 (possibly since 1979 or 1981).

Comment: +1 for program over app in terms of non-mobile applications

Comment: Apple tried to trademark the word "App" in context of their "App store" but the request was rejected on basis it's a common word. Anyway, in specific context of applications for iOS, it is not only formal, it's the official name of these.

Answer (score 9):

I've worked as a professional software developer since 1994. Within most software development teams I've worked in, 'app' was simply used as an abbreviation of 'application', regardless of the target platform. It seems that it's only really since the advent of the iPhone that it's become a more formal term specifically for mobile applications. Within software development, we still use it to refer to any application.

Answer (score 2):

Apple and Google talk about "Apps" even in their formal docs, because they've made a conscious choice to adopt that into their company lexicon.  Is that appropriate for all companies?  I think the short answer is: it depends.  Consider the domain (mobile apps versus windows apps) and the tech-savvy sophistication of the audience.

Answer (score 2):

The term “app” is no more esoteric and getting saturated in the mobile development world and also widely recognized by end users.

- Oxford English Dictionary records “app” as a computing term related to a mobile device ( +1 Barrie)
- Gartner says: “Apps and applications are two very different expressions of software. The defining characteristic of an app is its reduced functional presence. Apps do less than applications. That is their goal."
- Apple, Google and Facebook use the term “App” in their formal docs (+1 Lynn)and communication ( For example, Apple and Google employ the usage“App” in their User/Human Interface Guidelines).
- The term "app" has become very popular, and in 2010 was listed as "Word of the Year" by the American Dialect Society."