# App or app? When I refer to it in a formal paper

Tags: formality

In Android contexts, should the 'a' in 'app' be uppercase always or lowercase?

Comment: Lowercase unless it appears as the first word of a sentence or at the end of the name of a proper application. Why would it be capitalized?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lowercase, except at the beginning of a sentence.  App is short for application.  And, given that you wouldn't capitalize application, no need to capitalize app.

In a formal paper, you should consider writing out application.  At least for the first usage like this:  application (app).

Here is a search of the word app on [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com).  Note the consistent lowercase usage.  (Click to enlarge:)

[image: Used on Engadget]

Comment: While I'd also consider writing out 'application' for a formal paper, there's something to be said for 'app' being proper use to describe a mobile application - similar to radar, scuba, laser, modem, etc.  All of which I'm sure are not written out in every formal paper anymore.

Comment: @Doc I think that it depends upon the level of formality and subject matter.  If it were a paper on the application of scuba, I would say:  Self-contained Underwater Breathing Apparatus (SCUBA) and go from there.  If it were about underwater caves, I would say:  many of the newly discovered lifeforms can only be found by the use of scuba gear.

Comment: In the context of Android, I disagree that app should be defined as a shortened version of application. The word 'app', although (probably) originating from the word application, has taken on it's own meaning, separate from application. No-one would refer to a smartphone application, it is now just an app, separate from large industrial applications, for example. This is different from scuba where the origin is still relevant. Ref also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/45762/89735).

Comment: @zelanix I tend to agree with your point. App has grown to have it's own meaning now. It's just formal writing critics took a while to digest it. Now almost all technical book refer to this type of mobile software as "apps"